# Redirecting using location.href

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I am trying to redirect a user to a different asp page with some data that the asp page can use. This is the code I am using:

```
var done = confirm("Would you like to save?");
if (done == true)
{
    var concode = "<%response.write(concode) %>";
    location.href = "Main.asp?concode="+concode;
}
```

However I am noticing that information is showing in the URL after "Main.asp?concode=" which is similar to a html form "get" method.

Is there any way I can make this code similar to a html form "post" metod? Because I am using a `<%request.form("concode")%>` and there is information in the URL that is sensitive, such as the server name and password.

Or do I have to use a combination of AJAX and javascript to achieve what I need?

Comment: If by "sensitive" you mean you don't want the user to see it *at all*, then moving it to POST method does not hide it from the user if the user has a tool like Fiddler or decides to view the source of the page.  You should rather store it in the Session and don't transfer it to the user's page.

Comment: That is true. However, I have already confirmed that the user does not use those kinds of tracking tools.

Comment: Is this a public website?  You should *never* assume the user can't get information that is available to them, as long as any one of your users might have malicious intent.  If this is a completely internal website to your organization, then that can maybe be a safe assumption, but it's still a good idea to apply best programming practices.

Comment: @blazinazian so you've confirmed that the user is not attacking the user's privacy? Surely that isn't the fear here.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for your input. I will keep that in mind for future projects. This project, however, is web app for a completely internal website.

Comment: If you trust everyone who'll see the site, and it's not connecting via the internet, then there's no worry about "sensitive data". It's not a security risk that **I** know my banking PIN code, for example.

Comment: @JonHanna oh I see what you're saying. I was really confused about your first comment but this clears it up.

Comment: I'm not clear though. Is there a risk of people seeing this user's data or not. If there isn't, then why not just stick with the code that works. If there is, then you need to do more than just POST, because POST is just as readable as GET to a snooper.

Comment: Maybe I just need to be clear on my project. My project is a web app that is designed for a company to access their own server and interact with it. The problem that I have now is that employees will be using this app as well and I don't want server access information to show up in the browser. So in short: I want to make the server access info invisible. As for the risk, it is very minimal.

Comment: Your security depends upon the employees being completely unfamiliar with the web. Your utility depends upon the employees being at least passingly familiar with the web. I don't think this bodes well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to post data from javascript and move the page to the results (rather than using AJAX to do so without changing the page) is to put that information into a form, and then `submit()` it. The form can be hidden, or consist entirely of inputs with `type="hidden"` so it need not affect the UI.

That said, the only added security from this is of over-the-shoulder reading. Important, but it still needs HTTPS to protect it from eavesdroppers (and it won't protect anything from the user themselves, anything that the end-user shouldn't be allowed to see simply can't be dealt with through javascript).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Didn't know that there was a submit method in javascript. The more you know...

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. What you are saying is "Hey browser, go to this URL with this querystring" and that is indeed a GET request. If you want to use a POST request, you will indeed need some JavaScript and AJAX. For example the AJAX POST features in jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: So once i use the send() function with the data I want, would I use the xmlhttp.onreadystatechange property to change the window location? If so, then would the information that I used with the send() function still be there?